Derivative of $e^{x+e^{x+e^{x+...}}}$
Let $y=$ $e^{x+e^{x+e^{x+...}}}$
To find $\frac{dy}{dx}$, I took the natural log on both sides, which gives: $$\ln y = x + e^{x+e^{x+e^{x+...}}}$$
Differentiating on both sides,$$\frac{1}{y}\frac{dy}{dx}= 1+ e^{x+e^{x+e^{x+...}}}$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}= y(1+y)$$
Can someone point out where I went wrong?

What does this function mean? Is it the limit as $n$ goes to $+\infty$ of $f_n$ defined by $f_{n+1}(x)=\exp(x+f_{n-1}(x))$ with some initial condition on $f_0$?

What are the possible values of $x$ for $y$ to be finite?

I have no idea whether this function is well-defined and differentiable. But if we have a functional equation $f(x)=e^{x+f(x)}$, then $f'(x)=(1+f'(x))f(x)$, whence
$$f'(x)=\frac{f(x)}{f(x)+1}$$

The mistake is here: "Differentiating on both sides,$\frac{1}{y}\frac{dy}{dx}= 1+ \color{red}{\frac{d}{dx}}e^{x+e^{x+e^{x+...}}} \color{red}{= 1+y'}$"

Perhaps you need the condition $x \le -1$.

Think about Lambert function

If it converges, then $y=e^{x+y}$.  But proof of convergence will be necessary before you can do anything else.

From your $\log_e y = x + e^{x+e^{x+e^{x+...}}}$ you have $$\log_e y = x + y$$ and taking the derivative with respect to $y$ gives $$\frac1y \frac{dy}{dx}=1+\frac{dy}{dx}$$ which is equivalent to $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{\frac1y-1}=\frac{y}{1-y}.$$
You can go further and say from $\log_e y = x + y$ suggests that $y=-W(-e^x)$ using the Lambert W function, at least for $x<-1$, and so $$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{W(-e^x)}{1+W(-e^x)}.$$
Here is a graph of $\frac{dy}{dx}$ in red, also showing $y$ in blue.  Note that as $x \to -1^-$ you have $y \to 1$ and $\frac{dy}{dx}\to +\infty$.


We have $y=e^xe^{y}$ Hence $e^x=ye^{-y}$ which  implies $x=\log y-y.$ Thus $${dx\over dy}={1\over y}-1={1-y\over y}$$ which leads to $${dy\over dx}={y\over 1-y}$$

so this is effectively equal to
$y=e^{x+y}$
so you have $\frac{dy}{dx}=(1+\frac{dy}{dx})e^{x+y}$
you should be able to do it from here

you are not considering the nesting here...
$\ln y$=$x+e^{x+e^{x+e^{x+...}}}$
and as $y=e^{x+e^{x+e^{x+...}}}$
So, $\ln y = x+y $
now, $y=e^{x+y}$
after differentiation $\ln y=x+y$ wrt $x$
you'll have
$(1/e^{x+y})\,dy/dx=1+dy/dx$
